# Vertical text slider should look more circular

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper.js

I have creqated a vertical text slider with swiper.js. Next to the swiper I have created a ellipse with a gradient. The gradient rotates on each swipe. I want that the swiper is aligned "around" the ellipse. So I want to have 3 slides visible perview as it is now but when swiping it should have a more circular look.

I can't figure out how to make this circular swipe look.

```js
let deg = 90;
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  direction: "vertical",
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    sensitivity: 100,
    releaseOnEdges: true
  }
});
swiper.on("slideChange", function () {
  document.getElementById(
    "swipper-ellipse"
  ).style.background = `linear-gradient(black, black) padding-box,linear-gradient(${
    deg + 10
  }deg, darkblue, white) border-box`;
  deg = deg + 10;
});
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: black;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .mySwiper {
        width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }

      h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      p {
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      .swiper-slide-active {
        opacity: 70%;
      }
      .swiper-slide-active p {
        margin-left: 15px;
      }
      .swiper-slide-next {
        margin-left: 30px;
      }
      .swiper-slide-next + div {
        opacity: 70%;
      }
      .swiper-slide-next + div h3 {
        margin-left: 15px;
      }
      #swipper-section {
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px;
      }
      #swipper-ellipse {
        background: linear-gradient(black, black) padding-box,
          linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, white) border-box;
        height: 400px;
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        border: 8px solid transparent;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


<div id="swipper-section">
      <div id="swipper-ellipse"></div>
      <div class="swiper mySwiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>1. Analyse</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>2. Ziele festlegen</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>3. Strategie festlegen</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>4. Design festlegen</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>5. Implementation festlegen</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h3>6. Optimierungen festlegen</h3>
            <p>
              In dieser Phase wird analysiert.<br />
              und analysiert.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```